# Lucas Numbers Inequality

Tags: inequality, fibonacci-numbers, lucas-numbers

Can it be shown that

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\ln(1+L_{n}) -1} \geq \frac{L_{n}}{(L_{n}-1)(e^{L_{n}}-1)}
\end{align}

where $L_{n}$ is the $n^{th}$ Lucas number. Show results in full detail.

Comment: Is this really the inequality you're looking for?  The $e^{L_n}$ term increases so fast that the result clearly holds for large $L_n$; you just need to verify it for the first few terms.

Comment: "Show results in full detail." I wish Mariano were around to explain the impoliteness of the imperative.

Comment: Often math problems do start with comparing the first few values, but this only lasts until someone asks for a proof. Upon this request of proof, most, including me, often say "uh-oh" how to prove this one as well.

Comment: @Leucippus: have you tried using power series?

Comment: @LAcarguy A power series could work, but misses the fine art of a mathematical proof. Often problems involving a function expandable into a series can provide insight into the proof by the process of the expansion.

Comment: @Leucippus: The way it is phrased seems like an order. More polite would be "I'm interested in a complete proof."

Comment: Also, please use the @username construction when responding to comments. That will notify the person in question. I only happened to see that you had responded after randomly happening upon this question a second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ln(1+L_n) \leq L_n \to  ln(1 + L_n) - 1 \leq L_n - 1 \to \dfrac{1}{ln(1 + L_n) - 1} \geq \dfrac{1}{L_n - 1}$.

Also: $e^{L_n} \geq L_n + 1 \to e^{L_n} - 1 \geq L_n \to 1 \geq \dfrac{L_n}{e^{L_n} - 1}$.

The conclusion follows from these inequalities.

Comment: nice solution, clean and fast